a question on linear algebra and group action
Let $G$ be a group acting on a ring $R$ which satisfies the equations: $g \cdot(x+y)=g . x+g . y, g .(x y)=(g \cdot x)(g . y)$ for all $x, y \in R$ and for all $g \in G$.
(a) Prove that $R^{G}:=\{r \in R: g . r=r \forall g \in G\}$ is a subring of $R$.
(b) In the above notation, let $R=\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ and $
G=C_{3}=\{g: g^{3}=et\}$ be the cyclic group of order 3 .
Assume that the action of $G$ on $R$ satisfies the following equations:
$g . x=\omega x, g . y=\omega^{2} y$where $\omega=\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi}{3}\right)+\sqrt{-1} \sin \left(\frac{2 \pi}{3}\right)$ is a cube root of unity.
Observe that $x^{3}, y^{3} \in R^{G}$.
Prove that $\frac{R^{G}}{\left(x^{3}, y^{3}\right)}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ and compute its dimension.
(a) it is a subring clearly let $a,b\in R^G$ then by the defined operation $a-b\in R^G$ and if $a,b\in R^G$ we have $g(ab)=(ga)(gb)=ab$, hence $ab\in R^G$ for (b) $g(xy)=xy$ and in general and $g(\omega^2 x)=x$ and $g(\omega y)=y$.
Now it is clearly a vector space and $\frac{R^{G}}{(x^{3},y^{3})}=\{c_0 +c_1xy+c_2 \omega^2 x+c_3\omega,y,~c_i\in\mathbb{C}\}$.
So dimension is 4, what i am missing??

Please do not modify your attempt after receiving an answer. I rolled back accordingly.

$\omega^2x$ and $\omega y$ don't belong to $R^G$.
Let $P:=\sum a_{i,j}x^iy^j\in R$. Then, $g\cdot P=\sum a_{i,j}\omega^{i+2j}x^iy^j$ hence $P\in R^G$ iff $a_{i,j}=0$ for every $(i,j)$ s.t. $\omega^{i+2j}\ne1$, i.e. s.t. $i\not\equiv j\bmod3$.
So, a basis of your vector space is $$1,xy,x^2y^2$$ (neither $xy,\omega^2 x,\omega y $ as you first wrote, nor your next guess $1,xy,\omega^2 x,\omega y $).

look care fully $g^3=e$

Indeed, so what?
